# Help with naming a certain "tag" on screens

Tags: navigation, terminology

I'm currently working on a no-code platform that has screens with lots of information/data/boards etc.

Some of these screens are visible entirely, and others are only visible through other screens, in a window inside the screen.

I need to name both types of screens. In the wireframe we're using "published" and "not published", but I don't think it describes what's really going on behind.

Can you help me?

Comment: Hi, could you possibly post screen shots of each example so we can be sure we're getting the concepts right? Thanks!

Comment: For a better answer I need to see some screenshots, based on what I can grasp from your explanation , the " not published" screens are modal screens. You can use the page and modal